# Generate random integer weighted toward median

Tags: python, math

Where in the range 10-20 there would be twice the probability of 15 being returned than either extreme.

Comment: What kind of weight? Linear? Exponential?

Comment: That sounds like an order more than a question! But what weighting function do you want?

Comment: Done. The integer is 17. ;-)

Comment: @Chris Hmm... When I did it, I got 11   (>_<)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`random.triangular()`](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html) with Python >= 2.6:

```
n = random.triangular(10, 20)
```

`n` will be a floating point value, so you need to convert it to `int`.

Comment: Well, to be honest I believe that this is not correct.. You will have a triangular probability function but the requirement on the probability of the median being twice the one of the extremes gives an additional constraint. You don't need a triangular PDF, but rather a "house shaped" one.. The sum of an uniform PDF in (min, max) with value `x` and a triangular PDF in (min, max) where P(min + (max - min) / 2) = `x`, with the constraint - of course - that the integral of this PDF over R is 1.

Comment: So this is working okay, but I am having trouble using the bell-curve distribution functions in `random`. Say my range was `(10,20)` and I wanted values like 13 and 17 to be exponentially more probable than 10 and 20. These functions do not seem to accept the same (min, max) arguments, and the overall median is assumed to be the median of the `(min,max)` pair. Is there good documentation on this? The official docs seem sparse in information for non-mathematical people.

Comment: The "bell curved" densities are infinite (like all PDF functions), so they don't return anything like `10` or `20`. Their **max** is one (as you can't have a probability of two when throwing a die), so you'll need another function for that purpose. I'll re-write my answer a little (as I wasn't on a python-enabled computer when I wrote it) to fit to that model.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by Blender, you really need to be more specific. But in the simplest case you can generate a [Triangular Distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_distribution#Generating_Triangular-distributed_random_variates) from a uniform variate.

Answer (score 1):

Try and see if this works (sorry if it's not very readable):

```
import random

def randIntWeight(min, max):
  distanceFromMedian = random.uniform(0, (max - min) / 2.0)

  return (max - min) / 2.0 + distanceFromMedian * (-1) ** (random.randrange(-1, 0))
```

I'm still brushing up on my Probability Theory, so *please* correct me if this isn't right.

Comment: This returns floats between 0 and 5.

Comment: This won't work, you must add `min` to the returned value. Also, it returns a float and the function name is not very clear. (sh*t how picky I sound -_-)

Answer (score 1):

Another built-in function is `[numpy.random.normal][1]`

> numpy.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=1.0, size=None)
>
> Draw random samples from a normal (Gaussian) distribution.

You can specify loc=15.0 to set the mean and scale=2 to 5 to make the range of possible values narrower or broader. The scale is the number of standard deviations +/- of your mean (15) that is likely. It doesn't let you define a specific range, but you can always take the output and re-roll it if it falls outside of some range. This gives you a more nuanced way to get values around a certain value.

set `size=None` to return one value.

From https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html

```
mu, sigma = 0, 0.1 # mean and standard deviation 
s = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, 1000)
... (see link below for full code)
plt.show()
```

[image]